# How to Export/Import Vectors in R?

Tags: r

I realize this is a pretty basic question, but I want to make sure I do it right, so I wanted to ask just to confirm. I have a vector in one project that I want to be able to use in another project, and I was wondering if there was a simple way to export the vector in a form that I can easily import it to another project.

The way that I figured out how to do it so far is to convert it to a df, then export the df as a csv, then import and unpack it to vector form, but that seems needlessly complicated. It's just a simple numeric vector.

Comment: take a look at ?save

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of ways to read and write data/files in R. For reading, you may want to look at: `read.table`, `read.csv`, `readLines`, `source`, `dget`, `load`, `unserialize`, and `readRDS`. For writing, you will want to look `write.table`, `writeLines`, `dump`, `dput`, `save`, `serialize`, and `saveRDS`.

```
x <- 1:3
# [1] 1 2 3
save(x, file = "myvector.rda")

# Change x to prove a point.
x <- 4:6
x
# [1] 4 5 6

# Better yet, we could remove it entirely
rm(x)
x
# Error: object 'x' not found

# Now load what we saved to get us back to where we started.
load("myvector.rda")
x
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Alternatively, you can use `saveRDS` and `readRDS` -- best practice/convention is to use the `.rds` extension; note, however, that loading the object is *slightly* different as `saveRDS` does not save the object name:

```
saveRDS(x, file = "myvector_serialized.rds")
x <- readRDS("myvector_serialized.rds")
```

Finally, `saveRDS` is a lower-level function and therefore can only save one object a time. The traditional `save` approach allows you to save multiple objects at the same time, but can become a nightmare if you re-use the same names in different projects/files/scripts...

Answer (score 1):

I agree that `saveRDS` is a good way to go, but I also recommend the `save` and `save.image` functions, which I will demonstrate below.

```
# save.image 
x <- c(5,6,8)
y <- c(8,9,11)
save.image(file="~/vectors.Rdata") # saves all workspace objects
```

Or alternatively choose which objects you want to save

```
x <- c(5,6,8)
y <- c(8,9,11)
save(x, y, file="~/vectors.Rdata") # saves only the selected objects
```

One advantage to using `.Rdata` over `.Rda` (a minor one) is that you can click on the object in the file explorer (i.e. in windows) and it will be loaded into the R environment. This doesn't work with `.Rda` objects in say Rstudio on windows