# How to estimate a parameter in R- sample with replace

Tags: r, random, probability

I have a txt file with numbers that looks like this(but with 100 numbers) -

```
  [1]   7.1652348   5.6665965   4.4757553   4.8497086  15.2276296  -0.5730937
  [7]   4.9798067   2.7396933   5.1468304  10.1221489   9.0165661  65.7118194
 [13]   5.5205704   6.3067488   8.6777177   5.2528503   3.5039562   4.2477401
 [19]  11.4137624 -48.1722034  -0.3764006   5.7647536 -27.3533138   4.0968204
```

I need to estimate MLE theta parameter from this distrubution -

[![this is my distrubution ][1]][1]

and I need to estimate theta from a sample of 1000 observations with replace, and save the sample, and do a hist.

How can I estimate theta from my sample? I have no information about normal distrubation.

I wrote something like this -

```
    data<-read.table(file.choose(), header = TRUE, sep= "")
B <- 1000
sample.means <- numeric(data)
sample.sd <- numeric(data)
for (i in 1:B) {
  MySample <- sample(data, length(data), replace = TRUE) 
  sample.means <- c(sample.means,mean(MySample))
  sample.sd <- c(sample.sd,sd(MySample))
}

sd(sample.sd)
```

but it doesn't work..

Comment: Try `fitdistr` in the 'MASS' package. FYI this density is the one of the Cauchy distribution with location parameter `theta`.

Comment: what does this package?

Answer (score 0):

This question incorporates multiple different ones, so let's tackle each step by step.

First, you will need to draw a random sample from your population (with replacement). Assuming your 100 population-observations sit in a vector named `pop`.

```
rs <- sample(pop, 1000, replace = True)
```

gives you your vector of random samples. If you wanna save it, you can write it to your disk in multiple formats, so I'll just suggest a few related questions ([How to Export/Import Vectors in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102913/how-to-export-import-vectors-in-r)).

In a second step, you can use the `mle()`-function of the `stats4`-package (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats4/html/mle.html) and specify the objective function explicitly.

However, the second part of your question is more of a statistical/conceptual question than R related, IMO.

Try to understand what MLE actually does. You do not need normally distributed variables. The idea behind MLE is to choose theta in such a way, that under the resulting distribution the random sample is the most probable. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation for more details or some youtube videos, if you'd like a more intuitive approach.

I assume, in the description of your task, it is stated that f(x|theta) is the conditional joint density function and that the observations x are iir?

What you wanna do in this case, is to select theta such that the squared difference between the observation x and the parameter theta is minimized.

For your statistical understanding, in such cases, it makes sense to perform log-linearization on the equation, instead of dealing with a non-linear function.

[image]

Minimizing the squared difference is equivalent to maximizing the log-transformed function since the sum is negative (<=> the product was in the denominator) and the log, as well as the +1 are solely linear transformations.

This leaves you with the maximization problem:

[image]

And the first-order condition:

[image]

Obviously, you would also have to check that you are actually dealing with a maximum via the second-order condition but I'll omit that at this stage for simplicity.

The algorithm in R does nothing else than solving this maximization problem.

Hope this helps for your understanding. Maybe some smarter people can give some additional input.

Comment: B <- 1000
sample.means <- numeric()
sample.sd <- numeric()
for (i in 1:B) {
  MySample <- sample(y, length(y), replace = TRUE)   
  sample.means <- c(sample.means,mean(MySample))
  sample.sd <- c(sample.sd,sd(MySample))
}  this is not working